# First MFCC coefficient appears wrong, not reliable

Tags: c, signal-processing, voice-recognition, mfcc

I'm using this library https://code.google.com/p/libmfcc/ to generate the MFCC coefficients from a magnitude squared power spectrum.

However, as I understand it, the first coefficient should represent the overall energy. This is not the case with my results. Which is making me doubt the entire feature set.

F0: -3.77, F1: -2.78, F2: 2.13, F3: 4.47, F4: 2.76, F5: -0.00, F6: -0.58, F7: 0.76, F8: 1.49, F9: 0.62, F10: -0.44, F11: -0.26, F12: 0.58

- These are the raw MFCC features before the lifter is applied.

The only reason I'd like this coefficient is to help eliminate the features being the issue in my project. - I pass in a magnitude power spectrum 256 real numbers long, (originally 512 FFT), sampled at 16000hz. I'm pretty certain the FFT is correct as I've ran tests to check the frequencies being generated.

I'm trying to use these features to perform speaker recognition, but currently I keep getting false positives. I've tried using the generated features with neural networks, vector quantization and simply bruteforce euclidean and spearman's comparisons. Nothing I do appears to pull out the uniqueness of the coefficients between voices. Ending up with false positives.

I've been stuck on this for months now and I have a feeling it's a fault of my features. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Its tricky to get everything right from scratch, there are too many things to care about. The coefficients looks ok, but there could be other issues in your code. To save time it's better to start with a proven code, for example there is http://alize.univ-avignon.fr/index_en.html which have all algorithms implemented. Modern i-vector approach for speaker recognition is also implemented in Kaldi http://kaldi.sourceforge.net

Comment: And I wouldn't rely on that libmfcc, it looks like just a piece of old unsupported code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll check those resources out. Should there be a clear visible distinction between MFCCs generated from different speakers? I originally generated them with my own code, but wanted to use a pre-made algorithim so I could be certain the features would be correct. Here's my custom MFCC generation code: http://pastebin.com/pBAU84CX does anything strike you as unusual?

Comment: You will not be able to see difference between MFCC coefficients, it's very subtle. Your filterbank code is ok, exept it is more efficient to run dot product over filterbank range, not over the whole spectrum. But there could be so many failure points outside of your code. For example you might incorrectly calculate FFT

Comment: Thanks, I am assured my FFT is correct as I have tested a frequency generator on my smartphone and translated the max output back to the frequency by doing say (255 * 16000 / 512). Does the DCT seem ok?

Comment: DCT is ok too except you usually take just 13 coefficients out of it instead of all 30.

Comment: Alright, thanks for checking. I still can't wrap my head around why the first MFCC isn't larger than the rest. The one that should represent the total energy..

Comment: Well, you probably can provide the full code to reproduce your values as well as values on every step of processing pipeline. Also you can compare values from silence frames and speech frames to see the effect. The fact that your first value is negative is indeed suspicious, but that probably comes from your FFT values. Probably you have zeroes or near zeroes in some bands. c0 is not exactly the energy though it it doesn't have to be bigger.

Comment: Interesting, well here is the code I'm using now to produce a set of features, given an FFT input buffer. http://pastebin.com/fjCef3zb I will provide a full write up of the data as it flows through my system, hopefully this will provide insight.

Comment: Ok, here this is the full run down and results. I've reverted my DCT back my custom one.

[The filter bank code](http://pastebin.com/bmWA1LCM), 
[Generated filter banks](http://pastebin.com/5LUdtSrU), 

[Feature gen code](http://pastebin.com/Wte9zNAK), 
[Generated MFCC and FFT](http://pastebin.com/EVqAy7qD),

Answer (score 1):

Your fft values are unusual, here is the sample FFT from a speech frame:

12406.376 317135.746 995981.334 626224.382 2005596.535 4058142.702 1183111.796 1866254.816 3522858.721 340289.386 6767139.243 10894041.353 511321.852 27681515.387 32174731.584 2294241.072 3673880.557 4752891.334 1069708.546 5207759.171 5264486.273 305515.352 1036866.968 1332550.402 150743.522 3417229.415 2512512.261 546054.633 2096752.637 1243709.121 70430.472 1657224.619 1288489.174 915992.292 4282845.277 2132087.811 576691.932 4625295.075 1869747.185 14309491.048 40317789.470 10781189.643 7169652.741 30153832.551 3933090.444 13867788.202 26961212.666 6052446.164 5232152.170 8754440.126 814935.042 4239680.973 8643209.234 869299.756 8493450.137 8647922.201 1814417.128 652202.156 934195.600 72344.850 599552.325 520781.731 94066.862 24987.524 30704.365 14786.379 38961.829 25425.752 457.993 16805.918 21014.001 25724.770 64765.894 31916.339 5772.055 26097.199 14997.984 15845.304 33384.312 10655.138 12742.130 27660.958 4208.045 104839.618 126015.679 126905.152 92657.454 5423.333 6252.982 26137.014 8101.993 23840.536 96350.180 155396.746 111640.103 67379.170 191046.213 53822.423 199623.939 521401.332 240488.616 26096.585 27258.739 56939.019 6054.077 33565.473 17344.580 584.597 27900.058 72742.464 61239.311 13451.726 5192.935 4261.550 439.073 9722.589 18140.512 6855.937 26066.804 19903.202 1091.290 33014.134 42059.955 11662.442 534.955 13736.420 13481.058 48308.510 33231.743 12317.196 48160.791 115668.828 211469.841 163739.245 35339.914 47145.795 37257.335 9065.769 756.579 8372.643 8419.709 1815.682 1017.977 64.215 17711.483 25315.887 44022.134 91004.399 49687.288 1524.393 19627.319 23474.766 9001.670 729.851 11901.670 16078.190 26974.342 13843.501 5620.484 18436.224 27086.375 31720.334 42472.198 143007.306 138588.920 87433.057 108255.923 101891.401 73553.860 76565.005 31125.667 23054.414 75971.499 23780.864 68413.973 240216.065 148102.903 19623.293 8194.448 2725.753 32133.461 60279.038 21668.906 539.175 61133.950 80454.478 6585.491 21330.695 265.198 14129.337 800.514 41091.336 66797.293 42455.636 20263.426 973.230 2763.689 1136.641 5300.404 3128.763 2635.018 15487.226 16915.816 5770.127 4770.271 16645.390 13957.322 27129.323 13908.576 2281.975 63947.522 50889.733 697.118 18690.955 12249.632 1006.608 12672.938 4463.555 4693.099 2048.688 1486.160 12965.033 89367.085 57248.261 23332.704 18483.057 1450.837 4288.211 8512.221 9461.348 3105.038 976.106 8155.822 26873.908 44851.560 30956.465 7607.291 4517.811 25642.189 22606.560 12422.574 44612.224 74799.536 25034.774 197.800 2410.775 237.717 3106.175 7980.360 3960.008 8073.620 31488.422 8950.003 3459.935 666.708 7.372

Also, I'm worried you are writing "FFT per utterance". Speech must be analyzed window-by-window, not for the utterance as a whole. You need to split signal on windows first.

Comment: I should have been more clear, there is no FFT per utterance. That is simply one window from the utterance 'test'. Each window has a 50% overlap and is 1ms in length. What is unusual about the FFT? Remember that the data I'm showing is after it is passed through magnitude squared function.

Comment: Window must be 25ms length with 10ms overlap. The issue with your fft values is that there are zeroes and the maximum value is just 10., not few thousand like in the example above.

Comment: Turns out it is actually 32ms frame i'm using, 16ms overlap. I will give you the FFT pre magnitude squared, http://pastebin.com/mxgEF76f (This is again generated from a frame within saying 'test')

Comment: pre magnitude must be 512 points, how come you have just 256? After magnitude values must be in range of 10k, not 10. I'm about this paste http://pastebin.com/EVqAy7qD

Comment: Ah I see. So I should probably clear this up. There are two microphones on my board and the incoming sound buffers contain both left and right channel interlaced, sized at 1024. From here I demux the audio left and right leaving two 512 buffers. Regarding the point, I should have printed 512 rather than 256 before. I will post a 512 FFT soon.

Comment: Ok, here's the raw 512 FFT output - http://pastebin.com/GsALb9Kv I'm using this function (not magnitude squared), http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group___real_f_f_t.html#ga00e615f5db21736ad5b27fb6146f3fc5 The is the result of playing a 440hz frequency.

Comment: I suspect I may be computing the magnitudes incorrectly. Does that real FFT result look ok?

Comment: No, fft result is also wrong. Those are quantized fixed point values, you need to use floats (arm_rfft_f32) or you need to use quantized computation everywhere.